# Files copy or paste becomes corrupted

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, copy-and-paste

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.When I am using the default file manager to copy or cut files in it takes a lots of time and most of the time it becomes hanged at a point of copying.Sometimes it shows completed but files becomes corrupted.I have installed windows in dual boot and its totally fine in windows and its not a problem of my pendrive or hdd or ssd.What can i do ? I know we can copy using terminal but why not in the gui ?

Comment: i was copying a movie (mkv) file in a pendrive when it was showing completed (that select sign at the righ corner and then it was gone) i removed the pendrive and connect to my phone the video was not playing saying that the file is currupted!

Comment: When i again connect the pendrive with my pc and try to oepn the mkv file it was corrupted there too.

Comment: Slow copy speed seems like a bug report. Nautilus spuriously reporting that a USB stick is unmounted and can be safely removed while data is still being transferred seems like a separate bug report. Please report reproducible bugs to the bug tracker (AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker) with enough detail for a Triager or Developer to reproduce the behavior in their test environment. They cannot fix bugs that don't get reported.

Comment: @Nmath i have waited enough and used safely remove !

Comment: When i am using a different drives like i am copying files to a external hdd or pendrive , this problem occurs . But if i am copying in the same drive like from a folder to another folder then it's okey though it takes a lot of time then windows.and I have already mentioned that copy paste or cut is working fine in windows so the concern of "flash drive is dying" can be ignored!

Comment: I think this is a problem of Ubuntu as i have also faced it.

Comment: @max I don't believe that this problem is caused by a software bug because it occurs mostly when copying to external drives. That means the copied data is being buffered in RAM memory during the copying, but due to a flaw in the RAM it comes out of the RAM corrupted. The same flaw in RAM also causes glitches when playing videos from sites that use buffering such as YouTube.